# css modal show background content which makes less readable

Tags: html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, simplemodal

As currently i am showing modal in react on click of button. 
but problem is it is showing background content in modal portion also. 
so, my modal content texts are conflicted with main content.
can someone please help me to solve this issue ? below is the code and current view of modal in below image

```
.order-view-modal {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.8 !important;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10001 !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.order-view-modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's because you've added the `opacity: 0.8 !important` style to `.order-view-modal`. You're reducing the opacity and therefore you can see what's behind the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you've added the `opacity: 0.8 !important` style to `.order-view-modal`. You're reducing the opacity of the `order-view-modal` element, and assuming `order-view-modal-content` is its child, that style gets applied to it as well.

What you could do is create another element inside `order-view-modal` that acts as the background, and add the opacity style to that. This way the opacity style will not apply to `order-view-modal-content`. Check out the snippet below.

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.order-view-modal {
  display: block;
  /* opacity: 0.8 !important; */
  /* background-color: black; */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001 !important;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
}


/* Background element styling */

.order-view-modal-bg {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8 !important;
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.order-view-modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <!-- Modal markup -->
  <div class="order-view-modal">
    <div class="order-view-modal-bg"></div>
    <div class="order-view-modal-content"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- End modal markup -->

  <p>
    <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
    a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
  </p>
  HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
  </p>
</div>
```

**Solution for transition:**

To add your transition, use a class like `active` as in the snippet below to control the state of the modal. On click of the button, the `active` class is added to the modal's classlist. The default vertical position is `-100%` and the active position is `0%`. I've added the transition timing as 3s. If it feels long you can play around with it and find the sweet spot.

I've also added `box-sizing: border-box` to `order-view-modal-bg` in order to make the padding included in the height of the element.

```js
$('#open-modal-btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#order-view-modal').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.order-view-modal {
  display: block;
  /* opacity: 0.8 !important; */
  /* background-color: black; */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001 !important;
  left: 0;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* padding: 1rem; */

  /* Transition effect */
  transition: 3s ease-out; 
}

.order-view-modal.active{
  top: 0%;
}


/* Background element styling */

.order-view-modal-bg {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8 !important;
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.order-view-modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">
  <!-- Modal markup -->
  <div class="order-view-modal" id="order-view-modal">
    <div class="order-view-modal-bg"></div>
    <div class="order-view-modal-content"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- End modal markup -->
  
  <button id="open-modal-btn">Open Modal</button>

  <p>
    <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
    a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
  </p>
  HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now. but i want to render it from top to bottom in 2-3sec way can you please help me with that, because currently it is rendering within fraction of second

Comment: @umesh I've updated the answer to help you with the transition.

Comment: as your solution for modal creates problem when some elements have position:sticky property added new screenshot in requirement section

Comment: You could set a `z-index` to the tables header, ideally something less than that of the modal or just 0 if you want it to be at the default level of the z-axis.

Comment: Can you share the code or create a fiddle or pen?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this solution. You need to create one more wrapper around your opaque overlay background and need to keep actual model outside overlay wrapper.

```css
.model-wrapper {
        position:  fixed;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        left:  0;
        height: 100%;
        width:  100%;
      }
      .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height:  100%;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.3;
      }
      .model {
        background-color: white;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding: 1rem;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
    <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
    <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
    <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
    <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
    <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>

    <div class="model-wrapper">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="model">
        <h1>Order Data</h1>
        <p>This is content section</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as your solution for modal creates problem when some elements have position:sticky property added new screenshot in requirement section

Comment: agreed but you have to set `z-index` property of element to keep this one on top and others below this.